# Compare object property to validate json schema in same object

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a very simple object like so:

```
{
  "title": "A registration form",
  "description": "A simple form example.",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "First name"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Last name",
      "minLength": "{'$ref': '/properties/firstName'}"
    },
}
```

On the property of LastName I would like to compare a value with a value of the property next to it. I am actually comparing integers so in actuality my real world example is even easier, just minimum and maximum.

I looked at the json schema spec here and it seemed like this should be doable, and have tried using relative paths and the $ref object.

Is this not possible?

The reference is here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901

I am using react-jsonschema-form but I don't see where that would effect this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of reasons why this doesn't work.  The primary reason is that `$ref` refers to the schema, not the data being validated.  There was talk of adding a `$data` keyword to JSON Schema that would allow referencing the instance data, but I don't think that will even happen.